Mac::FSEvents Used Inside Class with AnyEvent::io no Longer Working
This code no longer works:
use strict;
use warnings;

use AnyEvent;
use Data::Dumper;

my $done = AnyEvent->condvar;

my $watcher1 = AnyEvent::Filesys::Watcher::FSEvents->new;
warn $watcher1->{__watchers};

$done->recv;

package AnyEvent::Filesys::Watcher::FSEvents;

use AnyEvent;
use Mac::FSEvents;

sub new {
    my ($class) = @_;

    my $self = {};

    my $fs = Mac::FSEvents->new(
        latency => 0.1,
        file_events => 1,
        path => [ '.' ],
    );
    my $fh = $fs->watch;
    my $watchers = [AnyEvent->io(
        fh => $fh,
        poll => 'r',
        cb => sub {
            # For Mac::FSEvents 0.20, we have to catch the case that @_ is
            # empty.
            return if !@_;
            warn "event fired";
            exit 0;
        }
    )];

    $self->{__watchers} = $watchers;

    bless $self, $class;
}

When you run the code and change a file in the current directory, no event gets fired. The debugging output in line 10 should ensure that the watcher variable has not gone out of scope which is a very common reason for failures like the current one.
This other piece of code should be doing exactly the same:
use strict;
use warnings;

use AnyEvent;
use Mac::FSEvents;
use Data::Dumper;

my $done = AnyEvent->condvar;

my $fs = Mac::FSEvents->new(
    latency => 0.1,
    file_events => 1,
    path => [ '.' ],
);
my $fh = $fs->watch;
my $watcher2 = [AnyEvent->io(
    fh => $fh,
    poll => 'r',
    cb => sub {
        warn "event fired";
    }
)];

$done->recv;

Change a file in the current directory, and the script terminates with a message "event fired".
I am using MacOS Sequoia (15.1) with Perl 5.40.0 and Mac::FSEvents 0.22, AnyEvent 7.17.
Background: AnyEvent::Filesys::Notify which uses Mac::FSEvents under the hood no longer works on my system. The test t/30-event.t fails, showing the same behaviour as my code: No event gets fired. The test also fails for CPAN Testers, see http://matrix.cpantesters.org/?dist=AnyEvent-Filesys-Notify%201.23;os=darwin;perl=5.38.2;reports=1. Although the output looks slightly different there.
Some time ago, I have written a replacement for AnyEvent::Filesys::Notify https://github.com/gflohr/AnyEvent-Filesys-Watcher. It does the same as AnyEvent::Filesys::Notify but with fewer dependencies. That module has the same problem with my current setup in the equivalent test t/30-event.t.
Obviously, the tests succeeded at one point. Therefore, I suppose an incompatible change in Mac::FSEvents, AnyEvent, perl, or macOS causes the problem.
I only have one Mac, and cannot test with other macOS versions.
I downgraded Mac::FSEvents to 0.20 with the same result. Earlier versions do not build anymore.
Instead of the file handle returned by the file system watcher, I have used standard input which works.
I have also tried Perl 5.34.0 and 5.30.0. Same result.
The tests for the two AnyEvent wrappers succeed on a Linux system.  The failure seems to be specific to macOS or my specific setup.

The second script does not work either if you add the line return if !@_; to the callback?

Also if you move the condition variable $done inside the class in the first script, I get a similar behavior as for the second script. So it seems like having the condition variable outside the class is the problem?

The second script yields real events, in other words, @_ is not empty. I have also edited the question and removed the usage of the variable $done defined outside of the class and used inside of it. Its sole purpose was to terminate the script in case of success. But the real problem is that you never get there because no event is fired.

It seems like the event loop must be in the same class as the watcher. If I move the     $done->recv; inside the AnyEvent::Filesys::Watcher::FSEvents class it works for me

@HåkonHægland, the condvars are actually not important for the problem. The problem is that no event gets fired, the callback isn't called. I have added debugging code to the pure Perl event loop of AnyEvent, and the select() system call used there does not report the file descriptor being ready for reading.

"the condvars are actually not important for the problem." See this version of the script: https://pastebin.com/zpjzidy8 it works if I use the condvar $done->recv to start the event loop, if I comment out that line and instead using the line below with sleep 12 (uncomment that line) no events are fired. So it seems to me that the condvar (and starting the eventloop) might be important?

@HåkonHægland, I've got your point. But the code that I am trying to fix does not contain any condvar at all. I have now changed the $done->send from the working version to make it clearer. That has the cosmetic problem that the callback is called forever. Anyway, your observation probably leads in the right direction. The problem must have something to do with variable scopes.
